# Get the clicked position of carousel with Recycler View and Card View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using this [CarouselView library](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview).

I have used Recycler View and Card View to create the following UI.

[image]

In each card view, I have added this carousel view and contains images inside carousel.

This library has the `setImageClickListener` that gives the index of each clicked image in each card view.

```
customCarouselView.setImageClickListener(new ImageClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(SampleCarouselViewActivity.this, "Clicked item: "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I want to know which image is clicked and from which card that image belongs since there are multiple card-views.

I tried to register the click event in the ImageView and get the `adapterPosition` of clicked cardview using `getAdapterPosition()`.

```
fruitImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   /*Hits only when another click event (setImageClickListner) is not registered*/
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int a = getAdapterPosition(); //gives the index of clicked cardview position.
                }
            });
```

When both of the events are registered then only click on ImageView (`fruitImageView.setOnClickListener`) gets hit, which gives the position of the adapter. I also want to know which image is clicked.

When I remove this ImageView Click listener, then carousel view click `customCarouselView.setImageClickListener` gets hit which gives the postion of image clicked but not the adapter position.

Are there any work around for this? Please help.

**My Adapter Class complete code:**

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<HomeSalesModel> salesLists;
int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.album1, R.drawable.album2, R.drawable.album3, R.drawable.album4, R.drawable.album5};
String[] sampleTitles = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
Context myContext = null;

public GridAdapter(ArrayList<HomeSalesModel> salesLists) {
    this.salesLists = salesLists;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    myContext = parent.getContext();
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GridAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.tv_country.setText(salesLists.get(i).getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return salesLists.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CarouselView customCarouselView;
    private TextView tv_country;
    private CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_card_row, parent, false));
        tv_country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
        customCarouselView = (CarouselView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customCarouselView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
        customCarouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);
        //customCarouselView.setSlideInterval(4000);
        customCarouselView.setViewListener(viewListener);
        customCarouselView.setImageClickListener(imageClickListner);
    }

    ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {
        @Override
        public View setViewForPosition(int position) {

            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.view_custom, null);

            TextView labelTextView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.labelTextView);
            ImageView fruitImageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.fruitImageView);
            fruitImageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
            labelTextView.setText(sampleTitles[position]);
            fruitImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   /*Works when another click event (imageClickListner) is not registered*/
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int a = getAdapterPosition(); //gives the index cardview position.
                }
            });
            //labelTextView.setText(salesLists.get(position).getProducts().get(position).getSlug());
            return customView;
        }
    };

    ImageClickListener imageClickListner = new ImageClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "Clicked item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //gives index the clicked image.
        }
    };
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can get the adapter position inside `ImageClickListener`.

```
int postion = getAdapterPosition();
```